# HTML bootstrap div button alignement

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<div class="panel-footer rounded" style="background-color: #B7B56E">
    <button class="btn btn-xs rounded" (click)="refreshNow()" style="float: right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span><small>{{nextTick|date: 'mediumTime'}}</small></button>
</div>
```

and result appears as:

[image: bootstrap button inside panel]

My question is: how do I align the button at the center of the panel?

PS: It should be inside the green panel.

Comment: Try to set `align-items-center` class for the container. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment

Comment: remove **Floate:right** from button and add **text-align:center** to this class **rounded**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove `float: right`. Then `text-align: center` should do the job:

```css
.panel-footer {
  background-color: #B7B56E;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer rounded">
  <button class="btn btn-xs rounded" (click)="refreshNow()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span><small>12 Oct 2017</small></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete float from button and add text-align: center to div element.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Full bootstraps' classes used with no tricks. Just adding `align-items-center` solves the problem. But do not use the `float` style itself. If you use the CSS framework, please be so kind to read the docs. There are a lot of features which are enough for not to manipulate the styles for layout.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row align-items-center bg-info">
<button class="col btn btn-outline-primary">Hello I'm centered</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following if you still want the button to be floated right, but centered vertically inside of your panel-footer div

```css
.panel-footer {
  background-color: #B7B56E;
  overflow: auto; 
}

.btnClass {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer rounded">
  <button class="btn btn-xs rounded btnClass" id="button" (click)="refreshNow()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span><small>12 Oct 2017</small></button>
</div>
```